# Solving a nontransitive dice problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a dice problem I would require some help with (especially problem **b**). Here goes the problem:

Player 1 and Player 2 are playing a dice game, where both first select one die and then they throw the die. The one who gets a larger number from the throw wins. Player 1 chooses a die first and then Player 2 chooses one. The dice are the following:

```
A: 2,2,2,5,5,5
B: 3,3,3,3,3,6
C: 1,1,1,4,4,4
```

So for example Player 1 could choose first die A, and then Player 2 could choose die B.

a) What die should Player 1 choose so that he always has advantage (i.e. > 50 % chance of winning) no matter what die Player 2 chooses?

b) Player 2 is allowed to design a new die and replace it with die C. Then again **Player 1 chooses a die first** and **then Player 2 makes the selection**. What kind of a die should Player 2 design so that he would always have the winning advantage (i.e. > 50 % chance of winning), no matter what die Player 1 chooses?

How to approach this problem? Is there an analytical solution for **b**?

Comment: clearly, in (b), if player 2 designs his dice as 6,6,6,6,6,6 he never loses

Comment: @user99323 But Player 2 can't make the selection first. Player 1 will select the die first. Player 2 can design a new die in C, but he can't make the first selection. Player 1 can select the die 6,6,6,6,6,6 if he wants to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to (a) is B. This can be easily manually checked.

Regarding (b); the reason B is the best die is that it "wins" both A and C, so player 1 will always want to choose it. What player 2 should do is replace C with a die which wins B, but which doesn't win A (else player 1 will choose it). So we have a non-transitive losing relation $\{(A,B), (B,C), (C,A)\}$.

Such a die can be `1 4 4 4 4 4`.